# Saving a bitmap from a variable gives "invalid parameter"

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I need to save an image to disk that came from a web-cam between 5 and 10 seconds ago from when the "save" command comes in via serial port.

To get there, I have the webcam going into a pictureBox.Image (using opencv4), and then 2 Bitmap variables. Every 5 seconds a timer ticks, and Stored_bitmap_2 = Stored_bitmap_1, then Stored_bitmap_1 = (bitmap) pictureBox.Image.

When the right serial command comes in, I try to
Stored_image_2.Save("C:\Users\GreenWorld\Desktop\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
and I get a run-time error of invalid parameter.

When I do the same thing in a stand-alone project with some buttons (inside the button-click event handler), it works every time.

When I do this inside the serialPort_DataReceived handler, I get all kinds of cross-thread errors. So, I moved the save attempt to its own subroutine, and that fixed that but now this.

I am by no means a professional programmer, I'm an engineer with a simple problem and I can usually write a little simplistic code to fix my immediate issue. Please go easy on me in the explanation :-)

Sample code:

```
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;

namespace Weld_picture
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Create class-level accessible variables
        int Welding_camera_ID = 1;
        VideoCapture capture;
        Mat frame;
        Bitmap image;
        private Thread camera;
        bool isCameraRunning = false;

        string Serial_command = "";

        Bitmap Stored_image_1;
        Bitmap Stored_image_2;

        bool Image_saved = false;
        string Station_ID = "GWM-PWS-01";
        string File_name = "";

        private void CaptureCamera() // from someone else's sample code
        {
            camera = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CaptureCameraCallback));
            camera.Start();
        }

        private void CaptureCameraCallback() // from someone else's sample code
        {
            frame = new Mat();
            capture = new VideoCapture(Welding_camera_ID);
            capture.Open(Welding_camera_ID);

            if (capture.IsOpened())
            {
                while (isCameraRunning)
                {
                    capture.Read(frame);
                    image = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(frame);
                    if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                    }
                    pictureBox1.Image = image;
                }
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SerialPort1.Open();
        }

        private void SerialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string dummy;
            char CR = (char)0x0D;

            while (SerialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                Serial_command += (char)SerialPort1.ReadByte();
            }

            while (Serial_command.IndexOf(CR) > 0)
            {
                dummy = Serial_command.Substring(0, Serial_command.IndexOf(CR));
                Serial_command = Serial_command.Substring(Serial_command.IndexOf(CR) + 1, (Serial_command.Length - (Serial_command.IndexOf(CR) + 1)));

                Serial_command.Trim();
                dummy.Trim();

                proc_Process_serial_data(dummy); 
            }
        }

        //*************************************************************************************************************************************
        /* the first timer is a 5-second interval. It's the "memory" function so that if/when the save-to-disk is triggered I can store the last-time-shutter-open image */
        //*************************************************************************************************************************************

        private void Timer_picture_interval_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = !checkBox1.Checked;

            Timer_picture_interval.Stop();
            Stored_image_2 = Stored_image_1;
            Stored_image_1 = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image;
            Timer_picture_interval.Start();
        }

        //*************************************************************************************************************************************
        // the second timer is a 30-second interval. It's the way to turn capture off if the PLC/camera box somehow goes off-line 
        //*************************************************************************************************************************************

        private void Timer_camera_powerdown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (isCameraRunning)
                capture.Release();
            isCameraRunning = false;
            Timer_picture_interval.Stop();
        }

        //*************************************************************************************************************************************

        private void proc_Process_serial_data(string Serial_string)
        {
            if (Serial_string.IndexOf("Still here") > 0)
            {
                if (!isCameraRunning)
                    CaptureCamera();
                isCameraRunning = true;
            }

            if (Serial_string.IndexOf("Sun's up") > 0)
            {
                Timer_picture_interval.Start();
                Timer_camera_powerdown.Start();
            }

            if (Serial_string.IndexOf("It's dark") > 0)
            {
                if ((Stored_image_2 != null) && (!Image_saved)) // in case there's 2 subsequent requests to save the same thing (weld stutter)
                {
                    File_name = "C:\\Users\\GreenWorld\\Desktop\\" + Station_ID + " D" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd THH_mm_ss") + ".jpg";
                    Stored_image_2.Image.Save("C:\\Users\\GreenWorld\\Desktop\\test.bmp" , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp );

                    Image_saved = true;
                    Timer_picture_interval.Stop();
                }
                Timer_camera_powerdown.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are lots of reasons you might see an error like that. GDI+ errors are notoriously vague and misleading. Without a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, you're unlikely to get an actual answer. That said, two common reasons you might get that error are a) some problem with the bitmap format -- i.e. trying to save an unsupported format, and b) some issue with file permissions. The latter could relate to some connection between a bitmap object used in the `PictureBox` and the one you're trying to save.

Comment: You're still accessing and trying to change properties of Controls from a thread other than the UI Thread. You cannot do it, simple as that. Don't use a Thread, use a Task and a [Progress<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) object to update Controls in their thread. Your Timers work concurrently with updates coming from other Threads, this can cause all kind of problems, don't do that.

Comment: Hi Peter, the code I included in the help-request fails super-repeatably on my end. I left off the use statements, but the rest is all there. when I do the picbox > var1 > var2 > save series of events with just buttons, it works (many times over). When I do the >>> and then save on timer, it works. When I run it through the serial command, it doesn't. So, guessing it's a threading issue? Will try the other 2 solves and see what happens... Thank you for the quick reply, RK

Comment: Hi Jimi, thank you and I was heading down a similar path. Thing is that the mystery thread must be created from the pre-built serial port component/library, but nothing I found mentions that. That's (part of) why I got stuck: I don't know what is in that component and was kind-of hoping not to have to dissect it... Will try Idle_mind's fix next, see what that does... Thanks for the fast reply, RK

Comment: You are disposing the image in `pictureBox1` _while it is still in use by that picture box._ The correct way of doing that is to first save the old image in a variable, then assign the new image  to the picture box, and then check if the old image you stored in that variable was null, and if so, dispose it.

Answer (score -1):

You likely be able to fix the cros-threading error by simply calling your `proc_Process_serial_data()` method within an `Invoke()` call.

Change:

```
proc_Process_serial_data(dummy);
```

To:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
{
    proc_Process_serial_data(dummy);
});
```

Also, these two lines aren't actually doing anything:

```
Serial_command.Trim();
dummy.Trim();
```

To `Trim()` the strings, you have capture the returned strings and re-assign them to the original variables:

```
Serial_command = Serial_command.Trim();
dummy = dummy.Trim();
```

Comment: Hi Idle_mind, thanks for the suggested path. Fixed the trim() thing, no issues. I tried the this.Invoke but must have lost some detail somewhere, because adding this created 15 fatal errors and it won't even compile. First error is that I have an **invalid token "this", in class, struct or interface member declaration**, then that a tuple (??) needs 2 elements, and then a list of no ;'s and bad }'s plus another tuple error. Will read some more postings, but any suggestions would be really helpful... RK

Comment: Found that, now I have `Serial_command = Serial_command.Trim(); dummy = dummy.Trim(); this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () {              proc_Process_serial_data(dummy); });`
and when I execute I get nothing. The serial strings still come in, but the routine never kicks off (or the results are lost in space). Camera doesn't turn on, no images, just crickets... Regards, RK